# Magnific popup is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I'm trying to show a div content in a pretty box with [Magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).
I read the documentation and I think I did everything right. But the result is not what I want, the result  I'm having is a blue border and not a pretty box with the contents of my div. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<section id="news-container">
    <div id="news-body">
        <div id="news-content">  
             <article>
                <img src="image1.png" /> 
                 <a href="#first-popup" class="popup-link">Title 1</a>                                 <div id="first-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">              
                    <img src="image1.png" />
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                    <h3>Read more</h3>

             </article>
       </div>


            <article>

                <a href="#second-popup" class="popup-link">
                    Title 2            
                </a>

                <div id="second-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">
                     <img src="imagens/transferir (1).jpg" />
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                     <h3>Read more</h3>
               </div>

            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.white-popup {
   background: #FFF;
   padding: 40px;
   max-width: 200px;
   margin: 20px auto;
   text-align: center;
}

.mfp-hide, .mfp-preloader {
   display:none
}
```

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.popup-link').magnificPopup({
    closeBtnInside: true,
    alignTop: false
});
</script>
```

Result image:
[image]

My fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/6s834/

Comment: Can you inspect that popup in Chrome? To see if any extra styles are getting attached to it. A style that adds that blue border. Try re-create this in jsfiddle

Comment: I have my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/6s834/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include jquery or Magnific Popup.  Is the limited css you show the only css on your page?

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle with jQuery and Magnific http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/8XFNY/1/ I believe you are missing their CSS styles (https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/tree/master/src/css) this is in SASS however, you need compass or codekit to compile it into CSS. Or just grab the styles you are missing and re-write em in CSS.

Comment: Thaks, i donwload from here: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/! I think is the same, i dont understand why this border appears and why de cross to close appears below and not in the right corner! The image I put is my post is not the normal aspect of the magnific popup right?

Comment: The fiddle that you put here works worst here than my example. There work´s fine?